# how to change image position using javascript?how to get div width in integer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

sorry if it is too silly.
I wanted to make an image slider on my own in pure JavaScript. so i used the following code.I am very beginner in javascript

```html
<div class="w3-div" id="img-div" style="width:100%; height: 480px; border: 4px solid black;">
  <!-- i'm not making image position absolute because if i make it absolute it is not fitting in the div morever the fixed header is not working--->
<img src="assets/pics/1.jpg" id="header" class="w3-image" style="width: 100%; height:473px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {

    setInterval(changepic, 10000);
  }

  function changepic() {

    //alert("changing pic ");
    var p = document.getElementById('header');
    p.style.position = "absolute";
    //i know that style.width returns string but what else i can do?
    //loop to slide out the img from div
    for (var i = 0; i <= document.getElementById('img-div').style.width; i++) {
      p.style.left = i + "px";
      //p.style.right= i+"px";
    }
     // loop to slide in the image in div
    for (var i = document.getElementById('img-div').style.width; i >= 0; i--) {
      //p.style.left = i+"px";
      p.style.right = i + "px";
    }
    //put random image over here or just relocate the first image
    p.style.position = "relative";
    p.style.left = "0px";



  }
</script>
```

thanks in advance,please help me.
the link to website is [here](http://yirusworld.000webhostweb.com).(http://yirusworld.000webhostweb.com)

Comment: the for loops have syntax errors https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
also, you are only changing the style of the 'header' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really understand your question, but there are some points that I think it makes the behavior wrong. You can give some example of what you are doing then I can help better.

- You are using

> document.getElementById('img-div').style.width

- It returns 100% - exactly the value that you set in your element. If you want to take the actual width of that element, you should use offsetWidth instead.

> var width = document.getElementById('img-div').offsetWidth;

- For your loop, because the img-div is unchanged, you should let the width of it to a variable - here is width - then in the loop process, js dont have to take the width of img-div everytimes it run, it only use variable width, that makes better performance.
- If you want your p's position is absolute, add position: relative to its parent